Easter building competition
As you've perhaps already seen on other sites, TLG is running an Easter building competition that we are invited to be a part of:

Our colleagues creating global campaigns have asked us to ask you to
  particpate in this years #LEGOEaster campaign and share your amazing
  pictures online using the #LEGOEaster hashtag!
As a special treat the Community Managers have decided to add a little
  raffle chance to win for those of you participating. So we've created
  a flickr account where we would like everything to be pooled and also
  hashtagged. (The Flickr pool is right here -
  https://www.flickr.com/groups/3447329@N23/ )
Once we pass Easter, we will do a Lucky Draw between all the pooled
  images. We will pick 10 raffle winners, each getting a goodie bag with
  LEGO related Easter awesomeness and a medium sized LEGO set on top.
What's required? 

Take a Easter themed LEGO picture (inspiration can be
  found using an internet search engine or by taking a look at the work
  done by Stuck In Plastic and Toy Photographers or some of the other
  instagram communities we have here on LAN).
Upload and share the image online (Flickr, Instagram, Pinterest, Facebook etc), using the hashtag
  #LEGOEaster 
Share the image in the Flickr Pool "RLUG #LEGOEaster Campaign" as a raffle ticket for the Lucky Draw. 
Add your first name
  and RLUG/RLFM affilitation along with the #LEGOEaster hashtag in the
  comment for the image to validate your Lucky Draw entry. 
One entry
  ticket per picture shared in the Flickr pool - please note that you
  can only participate once with each image - taking pictures from
  different angels and uploading them does NOT give additional tickets
  for the Lucky Draw.

Once the Lucky Draw has been completed the winners will be contacted
  via Flickr Mail asking for their full name which the Ambassador for
  the given RLUG/RLFM then will be asked to approve as a member of their
  community before the prize ships.

Happy building!
